# Desire2Learn Valence API version parameter

Tags: desire2learn

When issuing Desire2Learn Valence API requests, what does the (D2LVERSION: version) parameter need to be if we want to support LMS 9.4.1 and 10.x?

Answer (score 0):

These are the "API contract versions" and they differ by product component (functional area). There is a [summary](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#versions-and-migration)  and there are [more detailed explanations](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/version.html).

Effectively you will want kind of a "min max" process. You should look for the newest API contract version available on the oldest product component version you want to support.  API contract versions last longer than product component versions and a product component can support multiple API contracts at the same time.

Comment: If we specify "1.0" as the version parameter, will that still succeed if "1.1" is installed?

Comment: Yes 1.0 will still succeed if 1.1 is installed. For each product version there is a range of contract versions you can use. Use the table at the url below to determine what product version s are supported for a given contract version. And use the documentation for the APIs to determine when a call was first added.  Version Table: http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#versions-and-migration